# how to add a custom directive property in meteor Slingshot

Tags: meteor-slingshot

I use meteor slingshot for uploading files to Google-Cloud-Storage. In order to give my app on google app engine specific information I would like to add a custom directive property like this.

```
Slingshot.createDirective('uploadSpotAvatar', Slingshot.GoogleCloud, {
    bucket: 'bucketName',
    GoogleAccessId: 'myAccessId',
    acl: 'myACL',
    ...
    customField: 'customEntry'
});
```

Is there a way to do this with slingshot?